# Action on a transition trigger in State Machine Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, state-machine

What component can I place on a transition trigger in State Machine Action Workflow in order to solve this task:

1. I have 3 states: "State 1", "State 2", "State 3".
2. Exit action of "State 1" has "Simple Task".
3. When "Simple Task" is approved State Machine should go to "State 2", otherwise State Machine should go to "State 3".

How can I solve this task?

Environment: SharePoint 2013, Workflow Manager 1.0, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two transitions coming out of State 1, one going to State 2 and one going to State 3.

For the transition condition you need to test the outcome field from the task. I can't remember what the name of the field is exactly, it might be `Outcome` or `TaskOutcome` (I think the latter). Take the outcome, put it into a workflow variable called `Var1` (or whatever you like). Then in the condition for the two transitions put `Var1 == "Approved"` and `Var1 == "Rejected"` respectively, or whatever you want the tests to be depending on what your task outcomes are.

Comment: Is it ok if I place Task in "State 1" Exit?

Comment: Yep that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the same using either SharePoint Designer Workflow or Visual Studio workflow.

If the steps are simple and can be sufficed using designer workflow then go ahead with designer workflow. If you need customisation in approach then go ahead with Visual studio workflow.

Here are some links that can help you give brief idea about creating Three Stage workflow.

[SharePoint Workflow Basics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35074/SharePoint-Workflow-Basics)

[Code Project:Three State Workflow](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/477746/Three-State-Workflow)

[Use a Three-state workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Three-state-workflow-11b6c5ea-572d-4aa5-8004-59d393b7229b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

[Multi Step Approval workflow](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/496510-multi-step-approval-in-sharepoint-2013)